# Can the Windows UAC show notifications instead of halting with a modal?

Tags: windows, windows-10, uac, action-center

It's helpful to know what apps are running with admin privileges, and I understand why the recommendation is to use UAC. But even after using it for years, it's still disruptive. Especially during those times when it lags. I *could* set UAC to "Never notify", but that's not a great because I'd be completely blind to when a harmful program is unintentionally run.

Is there be a better compromise?

Say, when logged in and not idle, instead of this:

[image: UAC dialog]

Could I see this?

[image: Example notification]

I'd be comfortable trading the security boost of being proactive for the productivity boost of being reactive on my home laptop. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What you are looking for does not exist in Windows 10.  People have had no problem using `su` for over 2 decades yet feel UAC is disruptive.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for your comment. Unlike the `sudo` [cmd] + [enter] + [password] flow, I just never got used to this and finally decided to ask. Also, just because a behavior existed for years doesn't mean it's good. The Command Prompt required a mouse click (or Auto Hot Key) to paste text for years. Now thankfully, "Ctrl key shortcuts" are built-in. (And without eliminating the use of Ctrl+C for `SIGINT`.) UAC has existed for years, but I'm sure there's a way to improve this too.